# This is a transformer code using pytorch, but an error occurs when using gpu

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, transformer-model

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\envs\wonyong_tf1_2\lib\site- 
packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1371, in linear
output = input.matmul(weight.t())
RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #2 'mat2'
```

**The above error message pops up.**

**Here's the actual code.**

########################
'''

```
USE_CUDA = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if USE_CUDA else 'cpu')


t = network.Transformer(dim_val, dim_attn, 51, dec_seq_len, output_sequence_length, 
n_decoder_layers, n_encoder_layers,
                        n_heads)
t = t.to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(t.parameters(), lr=lr)
for e in range(epochs):

    for inputs in Data.get_batches(Data.train, batch_size,  True):
        X, Y = inputs[0], inputs[1]
        X = X.to(device)
        Y = Y.to(device)
        # print(X.shape, Y.shape)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        t = t.to(device)
        net_out = t(X)
        net_out = net_out.to(device)
        # print(net_out.shape,Y.shape)
        loss = torch.mean((net_out - Y) ** 2)
        # loss(net_out, Y)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

'''

**This is the code for learning using the transformer module.**

What's the problem with this code?
I want to use GPU :(

Comment: Could you at least check "USE_CUDA" is True?

Comment: I am not sure where the error is coming from but can edit your code to remove all extra `.to(device)` as you only need to send them to the device once. Especially your model. Try to run after removing `t = t.to(device)` , `net_out = net_out.to(device)` from the for loop and do a rerun and share the whole trace.